# Access DOM and Get Element By Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access DOM and get elementbyid (get image.src) from my html file that looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Diagram</title>
    <script> 
      function generatePNG (oViewer) {  
        var sResultd = new Date(); 
        var h = d.getHours(); 
        var m = d.getMinutes(); 
        var s = d.getSeconds(); 

        var sFileName = "diagram" + h.toString() + m.toString() + s.toString() + ".png"; 

        var sResultBlob = oViewer.generateImageBlob(function(sBlob) { 
          b = 64; 
          var reader = new window.FileReader(); 
          reader.readAsDataURL(sBlob); 
          reader.onloadend = function() { 
            base64data = reader.result; 
            var image = document.createElement('img'); 
            image.setAttribute("id", "GraphImage"); 
            image.src = base64data; 
            document.body.appendChild(image);
          }  
        }, "image/png", oImageOptions); 
        return sResult; 
      } 
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body > 
    <div id="diagramContainer"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

I want to get **image.src** from my html file, how can i do this using javascript ?

Comment: You already *have* the image source (in `base64data`). Where/when do you want to get it again?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i want a third party javascript that allow me to get the image.src (server-side for example)

Comment: The above is client-side JavaScript code. How would it apply *server-side*?

Comment: in what language ? ( example: php )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i don't know how i can do this and access dom to get elementbyid from this html file

Comment: @ameni: Your question is unclear; just repeating it won't help. How would any of this apply to the *server*? Everything you've shown is *client-side*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i just begin with this so i just need a solution to access DOM from a third party javascript

Comment: I'm afraid that statement is meaningless.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder like i have done with nodejs which require phantom to access and get the image.src

Comment: var phantom = require('phantom');
var sUrl = 'editor1.html';
phantom.create(function(ph) {
 ph.createPage(function(page) {
  page.open(sUrl, function(status) {
   console.log("opened diagram? ", status);
   page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById("GraphImage").src;
   }, function(result) {
    console.log(result)
    ph.exit();
   });
  });
 });
}, {
 dnodeOpts : {
  weak : false
 }
});

Comment: I need other solution (not phantom) to do this

Comment: To improve/clarify the question, use the "edit" link, not comments. But quoting a bunch of phantom code and then saying "but not with phantom" isn't useful. With what, then, if not phantom?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('your_image_id').getAttribute('src')
```

Comment: Code dump, no explanation, and not even filling in the `id` given in the question or giving any suggestion where or where it might be used. Not a *useful* answer.

Comment: please give more details, is a server-side js ? i don't understand

Comment: @ameni & T.J.Crowder Did you want to have src content on server side? If yes then in which programming server language?